# biber converting unicode URL to unwanted ASCII

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, unicode, urls

I have a UTF8 workflow: `xelatex`, using `biblatex` and `biber` for the bibliography, and I think I have come across a funny behaviour from `biber`. It seems to be converting silently to a percent-coding string (no trace in any log) a URL that contains one single non-ASCII character.

See the MWE with output. The URL contains one simple ü, which is being converted to %C3%BC. I would expect and wish the URL to be kept as it is.
Can you spot any mistake? As you can see I've tried the `biblatex` options that affect `biber`'s, but nothing seems to work, I still get the bloody %C3%BC.

Just in case, I manage my .bib file with BibDesk and I've checked it is saved as UTF8 too.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,texencoding=utf8,safeinputenc=false]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@online{verknupf_expo2016,
Author = {{Warburg Institute}},
Title = {Exhibition: \emph{Verknüpfungszwang}},
Url = {http://warburg.sas.ac.uk/exhibition-verknüpfungszwang},
Urldate = {2016-12-12}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document} 
Hello and bla bla bla bla bla bye

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above MWE]

I've checked that the .bib file contains the unicode alright, but it has been converted in the .bbl

Comment: With the newest biber (2.7) you can use the option ` --nouri-encode`

Comment: Ulrike you're a star. Is there a way to pass this biber option from the tex file?

Comment: I don't think so. The option is shiny new (and undocumented ...). But you could make a feature request. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues